# Shoe protector aerosol spray

Tags: air-travel, luggage, safety

Can I carry a shoe protector spray in my checked luggage to USA. It says extremely flammable aerosol. Pressurised container. may burst if heated. 200ml

Comment: I assume you mean on a flight, rather than a bus or train?

Comment: Not if you want it to be there wity certainty at the other end or for your bag to travel with you with certainty.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot, not as checked (or carry on if it's more than 100ml).

From [TSA's Prohibited Items page](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items):

> [image]

When hovering over the Carry-on, you get the following note:

> (Less than 3.4 oz / 100 ml allowed)

Anyway, other organizations (including IATA) suggest similar policies as well, you can safely say this is a worldwide policy.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I would add that good sense tells to avoid carrying extremely flammable products in a plane, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Olielo true, but not in all cases, I have seen cases where you start wondering about it... like when a passenger tried to bring gasoline with him in his carry-on and the reason was: it's cheaper here than back home..